# Why searchview is a null object reference?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, searchview

I haven't change any code last week, but this problem suddenly appeared yesterday.

Here is method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

When I try to open activity that contains SearchView, app closes. Logcat says: attempt to invoke virtual method `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener()` on a null object reference.

search_menu:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

What is wrong with searchview? I've tried all methods offered in similar questions, but they do not work.

Activity:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<> mArrayList;
CustomAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Objects.requireNonNull(getActionBar()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(8,16,38)));
Objects.requireNonNull(getActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare in menu xml the wrong type of `SearchView`: 
Change

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

to

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

also change:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

to:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
```

the signature of `getActionView()` you use is deprecated.
**Edit**:
In your activity's class, check the imports on top, there must be a line:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've apllied all changes, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Tried this before, nothing changes

Comment: From the code you posted I can't see any other issues. If you want post your activity class.

Comment: I will try one more thing, if it doesnt help, I add code from activity.

Comment: Added activity. May be problen in last two rows? I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Why `CategoryActivity extends Activity`? Why not `CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Isn't there a toolbar in your activity's xml?

Comment: I didnt use toolbar in xml

Comment: May be some issue with Android studio versions?

Comment: What is the version of your AS?

Comment: I suspect that you're using code that is either deprecated or even wrong. Did you copy it from an old project? AppCompatActivity and toolbar are the standards for several years now. You can't mix old and new and expect the app to run without problems. Drop the old Actionbar and use Toolbar. Of course there would be other parts of your code that would need update.